# Best way to redirect index.php to index2.php when getting high traffic?

Tags: php, apache, redirect, traffic

Which is the best way to automatically redirect **index.php** to **index2.php** when getting high traffic on Apache server?

Let's say, if i reach **1000 visitors / minute**, I want to redirect automatically all traffic from **index.php** to **index2.php** ?

Comment: Why don't you just rename them?

Comment: Because I want to happen automatically. Index.php contains resources that can not handle high traffic and index2.php contains only text

Comment: You could store every request to index.php in database table 'visits' (id int AI, visited datetime). Then you could get number of requests in last minute with SQL query. But it's hard to tell if this fits your use case (maybe you want to prioritise some users etc.).